# why should the madeleine tins start off cold?

Tags: baking, equipment, french-cuisine

I have a recipe for Madeleine's which calls for the tins to be buttered, sprinkled with flour and then put in the fridge or freezer for the remainder of the prep time.  What is the reasoning for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[David Lebovitz](http://www.davidlebovitz.com/2007/12/humpy-madeleine/) tells us that chilling the tins prior to filling helps the cakes to develop a "humpy" appearance, particularly if baking powder is used (which some chefs say to NEVER use in Madeleines). Also, since the tins are usually prepared by brushing with *melted* butter mixed with flour, chilling would keep that where it belongs instead of it pooling in the bottom of the tin.